# Responding to touchstart and mousedown in desktop and mobile, without sniffing

Tags: javascript, dom, mobile, touch, touch-event

So, I have a problem. I want to respond to a user pressing the mouse button (on desktop) or touching a div (on mobile). I'm trying to be compatile with evergreen browsers. This is what I tried so far:

- listen only to `mouseDown` event. This works on desktop but doesn't work in mobile if the user is dragging. I want the handler to be called as soon as the user touches the screen, no matter if they're moving their finger in the process.
- listen only to `touchStart` event. This works on mobile and desktop, except for Edge and Safari desktop, which don't support touch events.
- listen to both, then `preventDefault`. This causes a double handler call on Chrome mobile. It seems that touch events are passive to allow uninterrupted scrolling on mobile Chrome, so `preventDefualt` has no effect on them . What I get is a warning message saying `"[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080"` in the console, `preventDefault` is ignored and my event is called twice.

Obviously this can be solved by sniffing touch events, but the net is full of self-righteous rants on how one has to be [device-agnostic](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/04/detecting-touch-its-the-why-not-the-how/) and that [it's dangerous to detect touch events before the user interacted](https://medium.com/@david.gilbertson/the-only-way-to-detect-touch-with-javascript-7791a3346685).

So I guess that the question is: is there a way to do what I want to do without sniffing for touch events?

Below my sample React code:

```
function handler(e) {
    console.log('handler called')
    e.preventDefault()
}

export default function MyElement() {
    return (
        <div
            onMouseDown={handler}
            onTouchStart={handler}
        >
        Hello
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turn out [it's not yet possible in React](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6436). One workaround is set a flag the first time `touchStart` it's received.

```
touchHandler = () => {
  this.useTouch = true
  this.realHandler()
}

mouseHandler = () => {
  if (this.useTouch) return
  this.realHandler()
}
```

With the caveat that the first `touchStart` can be lost in case of dragging.

Quite disappointing.